# How to go to the Windows Phone Start Screen directly from within my app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, navigation

My app has the option to create many secondary tiles. When user try to pin an existing tile, the app asks the user to go to the Start Screen to remove the tile first.

Is there a way programmatically to navigate to the WP Start Screen from my app?

**UPDATE**
I know user can just click the start button or back button. But I want to detect if that navigation is made to set certain flags. And it would be a little convenient for the user if the apps could help them to navigate automatically.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to do that. Going to background without no clear purpose within app is a bad design.

Comment: why don't you write the code for unpin the tile from the start ? Or you can write code for updating the existing tile.

Comment: @David the purpose is to make it convenience for the user and for me to set certain flags. I a, showing a messagebox whether user want to proceed or not. If they select OK, that means understand the context of the navigation.

Comment: @asitis My requirements are unique. I work with hundreds of tiles at a given time. So I am trying to optimize the performance. I already know how to pin/unpin/update existing tiles.

Comment: @PutraKg In your case, the purpose is clear because your app says it out but the API that supports navigating to background only does not have clear purpose itself. It differs from other APIs with clear purpose like: `SMSComposeTask`, `PhotoChooserTask`, ... An appropriate solution is changing the flow like @asitis does.

Answer (score 1):

As you said "When user try to pin an existing tile" means you want to update the existing tile . Use the code for Updating the existing tile.

```
 public static void UpdateAppTile(string navigationUri)
 {
   var tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(navigationUri));
   if (tile != null)
   {
           var tileData = new FlipTileData
            {
                SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/small.png", UriKind.Relative),
                BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/medium.png", UriKind.Relative),
                WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/wide.png", UriKind.Relative),
                // other properties
            };
            tile.Update(tileData);
    }
 }
```

And for deleting the tile

```
 public static void DeleteAppTile(string navigationUri)
 {
   var tile =  ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(navigationUri));
   if (tile != null)
   {
     tileToFind.Delete();
   }
 }
```

Comment: I understand how to update existing tiles. The problem I am trying to avoid is calling this `ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(navigationUri));
   if (tile != null)` hundreds of times on page start. Because user can remove any tiles at any given time.

Comment: Hundreds of tiles in a start screen? In my point of view , a user Pinning a tile to start screen is for easy accessing the pinned item directly from the start screen without searching the item for long. I would rather go to the items page for looking for the item than pinning hundreds of items to the start screen.

Comment: I think your suggestion on deleting the tile gave me a clue. I figured a way to do this in a more straight forward way.

Comment: If you got the thing . its great :)

Answer (score 0):

From the UX point of view, you should already avoid such situations by disabling (or adding to the tile 'unpin from start' option) for the corresponding tile, if it's already pinned to start.

```
  public static bool CheckIfTileExists(string tileUri)
            {
                ShellTile shellTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(
                    tile => tile.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains(tileUri));
                if (shellTile == null)
                    return false;
                return true;
            }
```